# No such file or directory on command execution

Tags: bash, git, function, command

I want to clone a git repository with bash. Apart from that I need to execute several different commands and they all should be checked with the same part of code. So I wrote this method:

```
exec_func() {
    print_msg "$1"
    if [ "$(bash "$2" >> log.txt 2>&1;echo $?)" -eq "0" ]; then
            # Task success
    else
            # Task fails
    fi
    printf "\n\n" >> log.txt
}
```

Calling this function takes two arguments. The first argument is just a string explaining which command is executed and it will just be output with some colors through the function print_msg. The second argument is a command. I can execute another bash script with this function, but with the following command it fails:

```
exec_func "Update using gitlab" \
      "git clone https://${git_username}:${git_password}@gitlab.com/*****/${GIT_PROJECT_NAME}.git"
```

All needed variables are set correctly (git_username, git_password, GIT_PROJECT_NAME), the command works if I copy it to the terminal and run it. Also, git is in the path - to be exact: git is located in `/usr/bin/git` and `/usr/bin` is in `$PATH`.

Why am I getting this error?

```
bash: git clone https://*****:*****@gitlab.com/*****/*****.git: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$(bash "$2" >> log.txt 2>&1;echo $?)"` is wrong, the shell is trying to execute a commande whose name is

> 'git clone https://*****:*****@gitlab.com/*****/*****.git'

(all the line at once)

either you execute the command directly without an other subshell ( using $(...) already does)

`"$($2 >> log.txt 2>&1;echo $?)"`

either you use the -c option of bash to pass the command:

`"$(bash -c "$2" >> log.txt 2>&1;echo $?)"`

Comment: thank you so much! I missed the `-c` option!